# 90's Young adult fantasy novel with a shapeshifter character with purple/violet eyes

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

The novel itself contained a shapeshifter character, who I believe had violet or purple eyes, might have been female, might have been an assassin. I believe the character was not the protagonist or antagonist, but a side character that the main character wasn't sure they could trust. I also believe the shapeshifter character was from a race of desert people. I do know there was a female character, but not sure if she was the shapeshifter, the main character, or another character altogether. I don't really remember the plot much beyond that.

The cover I believe featured a kind of desert scene with one of the characters, and for some reason they kind of reminded me of *Elfquest* looking people, but not sure if any of the characters were elves.

I remembered a new plot point. the story involved magical weaving, like time weaving or reality weaving.

I thought of this while looking up Tamora Pierce, but I don't think it was that novel, also that possibly the main character was from Earth or something and transported to this fantasy world by the magical weaver character, at some point one of the characters has to learn to use the loom or whatever it's called with the threads of fate and weave their color or someone else's back into existence.

Comment: It would really help if you could remember at least a small part of the plot or the over arching theme to help track this down. How do the characters interact, meet, etc? What do they do? If you remember anything else at all you can [edit] those details into the post itself.

Comment: Violet eyes makes me think of Tamora Pierce, but elves and desert and shapeshifting feels more like Mercedes Lackey.

Comment: I was considering Tamora Pierce too, but Daine's eyes are blue/grey and she's from a mountainous region.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is *[Colors In The Dreamweaver's Loom](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1412233.Colors_in_the_Dreamweaver_s_Loom)* by Beth Hilgartner

[image: Front cover of Colors In The Dreamweaver's Loom]

> At first Alexandra thought it was a dream. She would just lie there in the forest, quite still, until she really woke up. But the birdlike little girl tugged at her hand again. She tried to explain: "I'm Zan, and I'm lost." The little girl only smiled, clearly not understanding.
>
> That was how Alexandra Scarsdale first encountered the Orathi, the gentle forest-dwellers. She woke from her own private sorrow into a mysterious, peaceful world that seemed removed from time. The Orathi called her 'Tsan, which in their language meant stranger; but as she learned their words and their ways it became clear that she had been sent to them for some special purpose. And when emissaries from the City came with their cruel demands, Zan knew what her destiny was. Only she could protect her new friends from the peril that threatened them.
>
> Zan's quest was to take her far into alien lands, and it brought her a little band of companions whose unexpected talents combined with hers to win a surprising success. Colors in the Dreamweaver's Loom is a fantasy in the grand tradition, filled with varied and fascinating characters and rich in color and adventure.

Comment: yea i was off about the cover, there is a shapeshifter in the novel, but whether he has purple eyes now i don't know. there is also a bit set in the desert, but no it's not the whole novel

Comment: I know this was over a year ago, but do you remember how you found this? And you can self-accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].